# equals method not returning expected o/p

Tags: java, equals

Please solve my doubt about equals(). I think equlas() checks content so in following
example it should print true because content is same of both t1 and
t2, But it prints false. Why?

```
public class Test {
        public static void main(String args[]) {
                Test1 t1 = new Test1(10);
                Test1 t2 = new Test1(10);
                System.out.println(t1.equals(t2));
        }
}

class Test1 {
        int a ;
        Test1( int x){
                a = x ;
        }
}
```

Thanks in advance

Comment: It does check content. If you write it to do so. Sadly, there is no magic... Also, worth to check out hashCode() too while you're at it.

Comment: You need to override `equals()` in your class. And if the instance of that class is going to be used as a key in some Map, then override `hashCode` also. In general, you should always override the `hashCode` if you override `equals()`.

Comment: The equals method returns true if and only if x and y refer to the same object ( x==y has the value true ).

Answer (score 2):

You need to override `equals` in your `Test1` class to get the desired behavior.  Otherwise, the class will inherit [`equals` from `Object`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29), which only determines if the two references refer to the same object.  Here, you have different instances, so `false` is the result.

Quoting from the linked javadocs:

> The equals method for class Object implements the most discriminating
>   possible equivalence relation on objects; that is, for any non-null
>   reference values x and y, this method returns true if and only if x
>   and y refer to the same object (x == y has the value true).

Typically you test if the other object is of the same class, then you compare the individual field(s) for equality.

Answer (score 2):

You should override `equals()` because default method compares the references.

The method below will compare two objects correctly.

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
            if (this == obj)
                return true;
            if (obj == null)
                return false;
            if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
                return false;
            Test1 other = (Test1) obj;
            if (a != other.a)
                return false;
            return true;
}
```

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to compare `getClass()`s; `instanceof` is preferred for a variety of reasons.

Comment: This is not a part of this question. Overriding equals() method is the point.

Comment: Yes but you shouldn't misguide the OP by suggesting a bad practice.

Comment: `getClass()` is absolutely the correct way to check class type. Using `instanceof` will fail the symmetric property if there are subclasses.

Comment: @SteveKuo No, `getClass()` is, in general, not an appropriate way to do it. Two objects of different classes may be considered equal without breaking the symmetry property; it's up to the subclass to ensure that the property is not violated. Using `getClass()` can violate the Liskov substitution principle (or, at least a strict interpretation of it).

Answer (score 2):

`equals()` [by default](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#equals%28java.lang.Object%29) compares *references*; and the references of two different objects (in this case `t1` and `t2`) are unequal. You have to override it to check for equality between members:

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object o) {
    return (o instanceof Test1) && a == ((Test1)o).a;
}
```

As a general rule, it's a good idea to override [`hashCode()`](http://docs.oracle.com/javase/7/docs/api/java/lang/Object.html#hashCode%28%29) whenever you override `equals()`:

```
@Override
public int hashCode() {
    return a;
}
```

Comment: @NarendraPathai Then `instanceof` will return `false`.

Answer (score 1):

You need to override the equals method in your `Test1` class. Maybe something like this:

```
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
        if (this == obj)
            return true;
        if (obj == null)
            return false;
        if (getClass() != obj.getClass())
            return false;
        Test1 other = (Test1) obj;
        if (a != other.a)
            return false;
        return true;
    }
```

Comment: It's rarely a good idea to compare `getClass()`s; `instanceof` is preferred for a variety of reasons.

Answer (score 0):

```
@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj){

    if(!(obj instanceof Test))
         return false;

    return ((Test)obj).x == this.x;
}
```

Override `equals()` in Test to check value of `x`